# I want to display Tablename,Size of table and objects using that table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a schema and I want to display table info like Tablename, schema_owner, objects using that table and size of the table in SQL. Please help me.

Comment: Define `objects using that table`.  If `package1.procedure1` has a direct reference to the table and `package2.procedure2` calls `package1.procedure1`, for example, does `package2.procedure2` use that table?  Or only if it has a direct reference?

Comment: *[DBA_DEPENDENCIES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_DEPENDENCIES.html#GUID-F9EA7DFB-5471-4B07-BDEF-FDE5DF57D1F4) describes all dependencies between objects in the database*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `all_tables` in a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM all_tables
where table_name like 'YOURTABLE';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.
The following query will result in a list of all columns and their properties from an specific table.

```
select col.column_id, 
       col.owner as schema_name,
       col.table_name, 
       col.column_name, 
       col.data_type, 
       col.data_length, 
       col.data_precision, 
       col.data_scale, 
       col.nullable
from sys.dba_tab_columns col
inner join sys.dba_tables t on col.owner = t.owner 
                              and col.table_name = t.table_name
where col.table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
order by col.column_id;
```